# Laravel Resource default method - update

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller called ItemController. With this controller, the method `store` and `index` are the only recognized methods. when i use the method `update`, it throws an error

> > Missing required parameters for [Route: items.update]

Route.php

```
            Route::resource('items', 'ItemsController');
```

ResourceRegistrar.php

```
protected $resourceDefaults = ['index', 'create', 'store', 'show', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy'];
```

**html**

```
 <form role="form" method="post"  action="{{ route('items.update') }}">
            {!! csrf_field() !!}

<div class="form-group" style="width: 400px;">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Item Name</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="name" value="{!! $item->name !!}" placeholder="item name" required="">
</div>


<div class="form-group" style="width: 400px;">
       <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Retail Price</label>
                  <input type="number" step="any"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"  value="{!! $item->retail_price !!}"  name="retail_price" placeholder="retail price" required="">
</div>


<div class="form-group" style="width: 400px;">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Quantity Price</label>
                  <input type="number" step="any"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"  value="{!! $item->quantity_price !!}" name="quantity_price"
                  placeholder="quantity price " required="">
</div>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>


</form>
```

**Controller**

```
   public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $item = Item::findorFail($id);

        $item->name = $request->get('name');
        $item->retail_price = $request->get('retail_price');
        $item->quantity_price = $request->get('quantity_price');

        $item->update($request, $id);

        Session()->flash('flash_message', 'Item successfully updated');
        return redirect()->route('items.index');
    }
```

How is this happening?

Comment: Please share more info.
The request details would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `items.update` route it expects the `item` you are updating, but you are not passing that `item` in the request, so the route throws an error because you are missing a required item to be able to know which one you are updating, does this make sense?

**EDIT:**

you need to include `$item->id` in your `route('items.update', $item->id)`

Comment: You were not, you were just calling the route without any passed params

Answer (score 1):

You need to be including a route parameter for the item you are updating.  If you run

```
php artisan route:list
```

you should see something like: `/items/{item}    App\Http\Controllers\ItemController`.

Your request URL should include the item id like:

```
`/items/1`
```

where 1 is the primary key for the item updating.

**edit**

You need to pass id to the route helper method in your HTML form:

```
action="{{ route('items.update', $item->id) }}"
```

Also, in your form, set the method as `PUT` or `PATCH` by:

```
<form>
    {!! method_field('put') !!}

    //or 

    {!! method_field('patch') !!}

    ...

</form>
```

Laravel uses a technique called [Form Method Spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#form-method-spoofing) to fake `PUT`, `PATCH`, and `DELETE` HTTP verbs via `POST`.

**edit 2**

You're saving the record incorrectly, change

```
$item->update($request, $id);
```

to

```
$item->save();
```

Comment: You're missing the id in the route helper, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I am getting a method not allowed exception

Comment: Include the `put` or `patch` method field in the form, answer has bee updated.

Comment: BadMethodCallException
Method [show] does not exist.

Comment: Hmm, that should be calling the update route, is it redirecting to `items.index` and failing there possibly?

Comment: Check my new update, you're saving the changes incorrectly.

Comment: This error is still there BadMethodCallException Method [show] does not exist.  I just created a show method though but then the update is not working. The item never gets updated

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` and find the update and show routes. Are they named correctly? I'm not seeing what could be causing that error based on what is included in the question so far.